# How to create tableView and collectionview in swiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I have been working on an e-commerce project that is for the IOS application. I am using SwiftUi for the UI instead of UIKIT. Now i am new to swiftUI and i have no idea to how to develop homescreen that contains tableview and collectionview. I searched alot but didn't find any positive or right solution for my work. Please guide me to how to develop a home screen that contains tableview and collectionview in swiftUI.

thanks

```
    VStack{
                    
             Spacer()
            .frame(height:40)
        LazyHGrid(
            rows: columns,
            spacing: UIScreen.screenWidth-150
            
        ) {
            Text("My Edits")
            Button{}
        label:{
            Text("View all")
                .font(Font.SmallCaptionTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.DarkGreyColor)
        }
            
            
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)    {
            HStack{
                
                ForEach(0..<2) { index in
                    MyEditCell()
                    
                    
                    
                    
                }}
            .frame(height:  200)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            
        }
        
        LazyHGrid(
            rows: columns,
            spacing: UIScreen.screenWidth-180
            
        ) {
            Text("New Posters")
            Button{}
        label:{
            Text("View all")
                .font(Font.SmallCaptionTitle)
                .foregroundColor(Color.DarkGreyColor)
        }
            
            
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
        
        
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false)    {
            HStack{
                
                ForEach(0..<10) { index in
                    NewPostersCell()
                }}
            .frame(height: UIScreen.screenHeight/3+30)
            .padding(.leading, 10)
            
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        
    }
```

I am attaching some of my code that i tried to implement.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, your current result and your expected result

Comment: i tried stacks but didn't get the desire result

Comment: Have you tried `List`?

Comment: yeah i tried them aswell. but the output was not good as compared to collectionview or tableview

Comment: In what way is it not good?

Comment: i was not getting the desired output when i used them. though stacks gave me some responsive and good output. but if you see my code i am using foreach and scrollviews aswell.

Comment: Add images of your current output and your expected(desired) output.